# Using composite key in AspNetUsers table in MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, key, composite

I'm purposely not posting any code here as I'm really just looking for some guidance to the following problem:

I have created a three new fields in my AspNetUsers table - FirstName, LastName, and NickName. I also created a composite key using those three fields. When I try to create a new user that has all three of these fields the same, the application throws an error as expected when the unique rule is violated.

I would like it to simply post back to the Register User form indicating that the NickName must be changed to something else.

Do I need to implement a Custom User Store? Is there a simpler way?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: There is no need to justify the way you have asked your question in the question body, it doesn't make the question more or less answerable.  That being said, There are 4 different variations of User Stores in ASP.Net: Membership, SimpleMembership, Identity 1.0, Identity 2.0.  Each handles things slightly differently, but each should already have a Key field defined; are you trying to change the core way that one of these systems operates?

Comment: Usually you can just catch the error and add a message like "User already exists" to the modelstate. Then return your model to your register view page.

Comment: Yes, I did end up catching the error, but I still think there is a much better way to handle this - I just don't have a clue how to do this.

Thanks for telling me how many types of User Stores there are, that will get me started.